# In Fedora what corresponds to chmod?

Tags: fedora, chmod

I want to use the following command, which is for Ubuntu and Debian users:

```
chmod 600 MOK.priv
```

However, I am using Fedora 27 and it does not work for me there since I get *Command not found...*. Does anyone know the equivalent in Fedora 27?

EDIT:

I want to run this whole thing, but on Fedora:

```
$ sudo -i
# mkdir /root/module-signing
# cd /root/module-signing
# openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=YOUR_NAME/"
[...]
# chmod 600 MOK.priv
```

2nd EDIT:

The reason why I want to run the above is because I want to install VirtualBox 5.2 on Fedora 27 by using these instructions: https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-with-yum-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/# 
However, when I get to the command `/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup` as shown below to rebuild the kernel modules after I have installed VirtualBox I get the following:

```
# /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup   
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.   
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.    
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.    
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.    
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
```

So I get *failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.*.
But I guess I have to make another thread about it.

Comment: Does it work when you call `chmod` with the full path `/usr/bin/chmod 600 MOK.priv`?

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent is the same command - `chmod`. `chmod` isn't a Debian / Ubuntu specific thing, it's a universal across all Linux / UNIX platforms. The path to `chmod` on Fedora is `/usr/bin/chmod`; if you don't have that directory (`/usr/bin`) in your path, you should. If you don't have the actual binary on your system, you have bigger problems as there is something seriously broken about your system.

Comment: /usr/bin and /usr/bin/chmod is on my system, so there should be no problems there. Actually I just wanted to run this whole thing:

$ sudo -i

# mkdir /root/module-signing

# cd /root/module-signing

# openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=YOUR_NAME/"
[...]
# chmod 600 MOK.priv

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in Fedora 27 with chmod: [read about it here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1525024). That what you're experiencing could be another bug.

Comment: I actually already disabled SELinux.